# What are these extra javascript files in my ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms project?

Tags: webforms, asp.net-4.5

I created a new ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms project and found a bunch of extra javascript files pertaining to GridView, DetailsView and other data related components as well as MSAjax. I assume they are to help with AJAX on data components, but I don't know how to use them.

I read almost every ASP.net announcement and haven't heard anything about these files and searched Google and didn't find anything either.

[image: Screenshot of scripts folder in Visual studio]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files belong to the Microsoft Ajax Library,it's a collection of tools similar to jQuery. MSDN describes it like this :

"Microsoft Ajax features enable you to quickly create Web pages that provide a rich user experience and that include responsive and familiar user interface (UI) elements. Microsoft Ajax includes **client-script libraries** that incorporate cross-browser ECMAScript (JavaScript) and dynamic HTML (DHTML) technologies. By using Microsoft Ajax, you can improve the user experience and the efficiency of your Web applications."

You can see the reference here : [Microsoft Ajax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee341002%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't see anything about GridViews or DataViews. The page says it is for ASP.NET 4.0, is this the same thing? Do you see any examples anywhere on how to use these?

Comment: Here is a nice cheat sheet (i love them)  so you can have a quick reference to the functionality it provides : https://web.archive.org/web/20130427115816/http://aspnetresources.com/blog/ms_ajax_cheat_sheets_batch1

Comment: here is a better explanation of all the files : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/21/asp-net-4-5-scriptmanager-improvements-in-webforms.aspx

Comment: How do you use the GridView.js? Can I just add a gridview and ASP.NET automatically use AJAX?

Comment: Yes, you have to use a gridview with a scriptmanager and updatepanel and it automatically will use that script for optimizations, you can check the available operations in the cheat sheet or the MSDN reference

Comment: So it's the same old MS AJAX that has been there since .NET 3.5, they just brought it to the forefront?

Comment: more or less, this modular approach makes it simpler to upgrade and improve the code, you can also move the files to a location that fits you better, i really recommend your read the links I gave you which informs you better of the advantages.

Comment: Can someone please point me to some examples of gridview.js or detailsview.js that exist in Scripts/WebForms? I can't really find any good examples. It's possible that I'm not searching in right places.